# Dudas o 4yuda con configuración de Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

necesito ayuda para actualizar mi aplicación en Google Play Store, lancé la app 1.4 (Es la nueva) y se tiene actualmente la 1.3 (Anterior), pero en Play store no me marca la actualización, aparte en Play Console ya me aparece como disponible y aprobada. Alguien sabe porque pasa esto, o como solucionarlo???
Gracias DevFriends

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Esto no tiene nada que ver con programación y esta totalmente fuere de tema en este sitio, esto debes de consultarlo con el centro de ayuda de Play Store, si bien alguno de nosotros podemos saber este no es el sitio adecuado para tu pregunta

Comment: Agrega más información, como te muestra en la Google Play Console la nueva aplicación?